# Jna loading issue

Tags: java, tesseract, jna, tess4j

Hi iam trying to Tess4j in one of my projects.
Every time i run,iam getting a error message

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.

```
at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native.java:1759)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:260)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(LoadLibs.java:81)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(TessAPI.java:42)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:379)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:292)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:224)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:208)
at ocr.main.crackImage(main.java:25)
at ocr.main.main(main.java:40)
```

Java Result: 1

Can anybody please help me with this.
I tried many tutorials,but cant figure it out

Comment: Are there any other dependencies the driver may require?

Comment: You are not providing enough information. The error message alone doesn't help us since we can not see the code that produced it. And the error will probably be inside this code. Or if you have not written the code by yourself and just include some library - you probably have *installed* the library incorrect, refer to its documentation.

Comment: Try storing the dll or lib in the `resources/` folder, then loading it with just the library name. You might need to place it in the folder of the correct platform (e.g. `x86-64/` on Windows x64)

Comment: JNA can't find your native library or libraries.  Run the VM with `-Djna.debug_load=true` to see where it's looking.  You can adjust this with `-Djna.library.path=...`.  `tess4j` should also have some instructions on how this needs to be configured.